# Your search returned no results after search category or product in the search box error in Magento 2.4.0

Tags: product, category, attributes, search, magento2.4.0

As I am searching anything inside the search box like category name or product it is showing not results error in the Magento 2.4.0 version.
[image]

Can you please how to resolve the issue quickly ?

Comment: Hello, please make sure your elastisearch is working fine and try reindexing again using `php bin/magento index:reindex`

Comment: I set the Elasticsearch is working found as mentioned in the screenshot:

Comment: sorry i can't see any screenshot in your question

Comment: Wait let me add the screenshot.

Comment: do you have tried reindexing make sure your every indexer is redinexed successfully

Comment: Can you please check the screenshot of configuring the ES please?

Comment: How to make sure every indexer is reindexed successfully?

Comment: If I search any category name it makes the query string as 

/catalogsearch/result/?&q=shampoo

Comment: @Waqer Ali : Can you please help me to sort out this issue ?

Comment: are you doing his on your local/